# C++ boost::spirit::qi recursive rule

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit

Using boost::spirit::qi, let's say you're trying to parse something like this:

```
object.member()
```

You could use a rule like:

```
member_access_rule =
symbol_rule >> '.' >> symbol_rule >> '(' >> ')'
;
```

But, what if you wanted to parse:

```
object.member().member()
```

or

```
object.member().member().member()
```

Seemingly, you would use a rule along these lines:

```
member_access_rule =
  ( member_access_rule >> '.' >> symbol_rule >> '(' >> ')' )
| ( symbol_rule >> '.' >> symbol_rule >> '(' >> ')' )
;
```

But this does not work.

In the above formation, the first sub-rule within 'member_access_rule' is itself and therefore the recursive calls to 'member_access_rule' will pile up without ever trying to match the alternative.

How can I get around this?

Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, PEG is susceptible to the infamous left-recursion.

I'd simply refactor the rule to

```
member_access_rule = 
  ( symbol_rule >> '.' >> symbol_rule >> '(' >> ')' )
| ( member_access_rule >> '.' >> symbol_rule >> '(' >> ')' )
;
```

Or, for that matter:

```
member_access_rule = 
  symbol_rule >> +('.' >> symbol_rule) >> '(' >> ')';
```

Comment: sehe, thanks for your quick and excellent answer, as always. Perhaps I am missing something or haven't properly encapsulated my use case for this post, but I don't think your first version will work in parsing something like "object.member().member()" because the parser will match "object.member()" and then exit the rule without noticing the trailing ".member()". If there's no better work around, I can now see how to rework things in my AST in order to accommodate the general spirit of what you're getting at. Thanks, this is very helpful.

Comment: Oops. I misread the samples. It would be more like `(symbol_rule >> - (lit('(') >> ')')) % '.' ;` perhaps

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks so much for your help. I was able to successfully implement this based on your suggestions.